# How to combine newman collection test results into one valid xml file for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

I've got a small Jenkins pipeline which tests different Postman collections sequentially and after that I combine the single XML files into one to pass them to Jenkins as a result.

Pipeline snippet:

```
...
steps {
  script {
    try {
        sh '(cd ./integrativeTests/collections && rm -rf *.xml)'
        sh '(cd ./integrativeTests/collections && npm run tests-all)'

        sh '''
        cd ./integrativeTests/collections

        echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' > newman_dev_results.xml
        echo '<testsuites>' >> newman_dev_results.xml

        for f in COLLECTION-*.xml
        do
          echo $(sed 1,$(expr $(grep -m1 -n "<testsuite" ${f} | cut -f1 -d:) - 1)d ${f}) >> newman_dev_results.xml
        done

        echo '</testsuites>' >> newman_dev_results.xml
        cat newman_dev_results.xml
        '''

        sh '(cp ./integrativeTests/collections/newman_dev_results.xml ./newman_results.xml)'
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
    } catch(Exception e) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
    junit 'newman_results.xml'
  }
}
...
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

[image: xml screenshot]

But sadly I get an ERROR in the Jenkins log:

```
ERROR: None of the test reports contained any result
Finished: FAILURE
```

What's the correct xml-layout for a test result with multiple collections for Jenkins or how do I pass multiple test results to Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in the [official docs of the Junit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) I don't need to combine all xml by myself and pass a single file. I just need to pass all XMLs at once with a wildcard.

**Pipeline:**

```
...
steps {
    script {
        try {
            sh '(cd ./integrativeTests/collections && npm run tests-all)'
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
        } catch(Exception e) {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        }
        sh 'junit-viewer --results=./integrativeTests/collections --save=result.html'
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'result.html', fingerprint: true
        junit '**/integrativeTests/collections/COLLECTION-*.xml'
    }
}
...
```